# Exploit prepared statements with both concatenation and parameters

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Is it possible to exploit prepared statements that both joins strings and uses parameters? If so, how?

```java
PreparedStatement prepstmt = 
    conn.prepareStatement("SELECT productId, price FROM products WHERE productId = ?" 
                     + "UNION SELECT productId, price FROM oldProducts WHERE productId = ?");

prepstmt.setString(1, productId);
prepstmt.setString(2, productId);
```

My first idea was that it is possible to exploit using `productId = 'a' OR 1=1\` but I can't make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your prepared statement looks sound, you have two parameters and nothing else, there is nothing that is not being prepared / escaped.

Answer (score 1):

The risk of SQL injection doesn't come from joining fixed strings. I could do the following and it would be safe:

```
String sql = "SELECT " + "*" + " FROM " + "mytable" + " WHERE " + ...
```

The point is every part of this string is fixed at the time Java is compiled. None of it comes from any unsafe content.

The risky part of SQL injection is that *unsafe content* may enter your SQL string before it is prepared. So the unsafe content can affect the SQL syntax that gets parsed during prepare.

Some developers assume "unsafe content" is the same as user input, but it could come from other sources, like reading files, responses from web services, or even string data that were previously stored in a database.

Use parameters for the unknown content, and used fixed strings for the rest, and you'll be safe. It doesn't matter if you build the query by concatenation, as long as each substring you concatenate is itself safe.

P.S.: Remember to pad your substrings with spaces. Your example you show above will result in the following:

```
SELECT productId, price FROM products WHERE productId = ?UNION SELECT productId, price FROM oldProducts WHERE productId = ?
```

This could be a problem depending on the SQL parser, because you might need a space separating `?UNION` — make sure it is `? UNION`

Comment: Thank you Bill! I have one further question regarding the space padding, is it exploitable or would it simply result in invalid SQL syntax?

Comment: It is not exploitable in any implementation. On some implementations of SQL parsers, it may result in invalid syntax. The query would not run at all, and therefore it would not be exploitable. I just tested MySQL and it's invalid syntax. There may be some other implementations in another brand of SQL software, where it will work as intended, providing a parameter placeholder, and that's not exploitable either.